Facing issue in restarting Ubuntu
I am using Ubuntu.
I was trying to install Cursor IDE. The IDE was installed successfully, but my file manager disappeared from the dock, so I decided to restart my system.


What is a curser ide?

reboot into Recovery Mode ... in its menu choose to get a root prompt ... from there you can issue commands in a terminal to fix your issues ... my guess is you have deleted needed packages ... at terminal type in ... sudo apt-get update and then
sudo apt-get upgrade  and then
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install 

I follow your steps but but still showing same error

Follow this guide, but don't close the terminal, I bet something with your system packages is corrupted. Run apt reinstall '~i'. This will reinstall all packages that can be downloaded. This might take a while. After it finishes, run reboot to reboot your system.
Hope this helps.

I am facing this issue because I have installed fuse . I follow all the steps that are in guide. And i also remove my fuse package.  Then I install Ubuntu-session . Then reboot the system.  Now my system working fine

Good to hear!! Hope you enjoy your system :D
